# Can't set focus() on a text field

Tags: javascript, sammy.js

This is just the weirdest thing. I've got a Sammy.js app, and I want to set focus on a text field right after the HTML loads. I've got this CoffeeScript here:

```
this.partial('templates/my-template.jqt').then ->
  i = $('#item')
  debugger
  i.focus()
```

While I'm in the debugger, right on that line, I can inspect "i" and see that it's a JQuery object. I can even call i.val("HI THERE!") and see my text field update. But, calling i.focus() does absolutely nothing. Is there some security feature I'm missing that doesn't let you focus on a text element that was dynamically loaded?

Comment: Btw, how do you know what you can do ".then" on the partial? I can't, for the life of me, figure out what the "partial" method returns from Sammy.js api docs. How do you figure that stuff out?

Answer (score 14):

Try:

```
setTimeout(function() { $('#item').focus() }, 1);
```

It's quite common issue. For some reason delaying the focus for 1ms makes it working.

Comment: What. The. Heck.   +1000 internets

Answer (score 1):

JQuery's focus() doesn't focus on an element, it binds an event handler to focus.
http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Try i.get().focus() instead.

Comment: Actually, when I do $('input[type=text]').focus(), it works in Chrome, but not iOS. Here's the actual file: https://github.com/pkulak/mealfire_mobile/blob/master/coffeescripts/add_extra.coffee

Comment: When I try `i.get().focus()` in Chrome, I get "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLInputElement] has no method 'focus'".

Comment: Also re: "JQuery's focus() doesn't focus on an element, it binds an event handler to focus": With no arguments, it does not bind an event handler; it triggers one.

Comment: LarsH, That's because you're calling focus() on an array of elements.  You can do this: i.get(0).focus() instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you are getting `$('#item')` object.You can try out few things.

Make sure that you have only one input box with `<input type="text" id="item" />`.Same id should not be repeated.

Next thing is why dont you try `$('#item').focus()`.

Thanks.
with regards,

**Wasim**

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
i.trigger 'focus'
```